# Is there a way to save the installed app list on Windows 8 RP?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I'm testing the Windows 8 Release Preview. I installed lots of apps from the Store. Is there any way to save (or maybe sync with a Windows Live account) the installed app list, and install these saved applications in the future - in the RTM version of the OS?

I'm talking about something like on Apple's devices, like iCloud. You can install apps on an iPhone and sync with your iCloud account. Then you can re-install these apps on another device that you're logged into iCloud on.

Comment: At first I thought you meant Windows RT but then released RP = Release Preview. I believe the marketplace will remember your transactions and allow you to re-download purchased apps

Comment: With Win 8 having been release to MSDN and about to be released to the general public, do you mind updating this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view previously purchased apps within the store through the folowing:

1. Within the store, right-click (swipe down from the top edge) and select "Your Apps":

   [image]
2. From there you'll be presented with a list of apps that you've purchased:

   [image]

You can sort this list by:

- All Apps
- Apps not installed on this computer
- Apps installed on other computers

[image]